# Completely hide a wrapping text on button

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to build a bar with buttons with button text responsive to available width. When the width gets smaller, and the (long) text starts to wrap, other alternative (shorter) text should be shown. I've done attempts with CSS grid, Flexbox and a translateY (100% - 1em) which seemed promising but I couldn't get it work properly as the combination of absolute positioning within Flexbox.

I want to achieve this with pure CSS, without javascript and media queries. How to achieve this?

This is the CSS (basic setup, doesn't work however)

```css
.button-bar {
     width: 100%;
     height: 10rem;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .button-bar button {
     background: green;
     padding: 1em;
     margin: 1.5rem;
     height: 3em;
}
 .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper {
     display: flex;
     background: yellow;
     height: 1em;
     overflow-y: hidden;
}
 .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper .button-text {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 1em;
}
 .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper .button-text .long {
     background: orange;
}
 .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper .button-text .short {
     background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-bar">
  <button class="button">
        <div class="button-text-wrapper">
          <div class="button-text">
            <div class="button-text long">Create Account</div>
            <div class="button-text short">Submit</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
  <button class="button">
        <div class="button-text-wrapper">
          <div class="button-text">
            <div class="button-text  long">Save details</div>
            <div class="button-text short">Update</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
  <button class="button">
        <div class="button-text-wrapper">
          <div class="button-text">
            <div class="button-text long">Dump my screen now</div>
            <div class="button-text short">Print</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the reason to no media queries?

Comment: you can use  `text-overflow: ellipsis;` long text to truncate in small devices . click here a [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow_hover)

Comment: @Simplicius: as the width of the text may vary dependent on language. Also, this bar can used in components, and it shouldn't dependent on the width of the screen, but just on the width of the containing component.

Comment: elliipsis will truncate the text, but that is not what I want. For example: if 'Create Account'  doesn't fit in one line, (height 1em), then it should disappear and the text 'submit'  should be shown.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for assisting on this post. I'd liike to include the css in the snippett, but can't find the way how to do this. Just pasting it in doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: You can not do that with CSS, you need to have a way to register that the text breaks or  the width of the container gets smaller than the width of the text, you either need to use media queries or JS

Comment: Click edit, scroll down, click edit above snippet and then paste in the CSS frame

Comment: @mplungjan did that but CSS is not applied.

Comment: @mplungjan if I know cliick on 'Run Code Snippet', the colors of the buttons are now shown, i.e. the css (SCSS) is not applied.

Comment: Translate the scss to plain css first: https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css I just did it for you

Answer (score 0):

```css
            .button-bar {
                width: 100%;
                height: 10rem;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .button-bar button {
                background: green;
                padding: 1em;
                margin: 1.5rem;
                height: 3em;
            }
            .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper {
                display: flex;
                background: yellow;
                height: 1em;
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }
            .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper .button-text {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                height: 1em;
            }
            .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper .button-text #create:before {
                background: orange;
                content: 'Create Account';
            }

            .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper .button-text #save:before {
                background: orange;
                content: 'Save details';
            }

            .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper .button-text #print:before {
                background: orange;
                content: 'Dump my screen now';
            }
            
            @media (max-width: 600px) {
                .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper .button-text #create:before {
                    background: tomato;
                    content: 'Submit';
                }

                .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper .button-text #save:before {
                    background: tomato;
                    content: 'Update';
                }

                .button-bar button .button-text-wrapper .button-text #print:before {
                    background: tomato;
                    content: 'Print';
                }
            }
```

```html
<div class="button-bar">
            <button class="button">
                <div class="button-text-wrapper">
                    <div class="button-text">
                        <div class="button-text" id='create'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </button>
            <button class="button">
                <div class="button-text-wrapper">
                    <div class="button-text">
                        <div class="button-text" id='save'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </button>
            <button class="button">
                <div class="button-text-wrapper">
                    <div class="button-text">
                        <div class="button-text" id='print'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
```

I still don't understand why you need to it only through css

Answer (score 0):

Based on your suggestions, I have found a solution myself. Basically it uses an absolute positioned element for the short text and a relative position under it for the long(er) text in a containing div called 'button-text'. By default, the height of the short-text div is calculate to zero, thus not visible.

On decreasing the width, the long-text will wrap, having a long-text height of 5.2em. As a result, the height of the containing div 'button-text' increases and the long-text translates itself. Standard, the translation is zero. As soon as it is larger than the expected non-wrapped text (2.6em in this case), it translates out of sight (100% - 2.6em);

At the same time, the height of the short-text calculates into 2.6em and becomes visible on the absolute position of top: 0;

Snippet attached is the basic layout. It can be extended to [wrap-to-icon button](https://codepen.io/erwinvanlun/pen/oNLgvYN) when the short-text would wrap as well, and be implemented in a [button bar with intelligent syncing of button-text to icons](https://codepen.io/erwinvanlun/pen/JjXZrYN) as that was the original aim of the project.

Hope this helps! Many thanks again for your inspiration :-).

```css
.button-container {
  width: 80vw;
  left: 10vw;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  background: white;
}

.button-container button.button {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 2.6em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  min-width: 3em;
  color: #333;
  background-image: radial-gradient(red, yellow, green);
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: default;
}

.button-container button.button .button-text {
  width: 200%;
}

.button-container button.button .button-text .long {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-container button.button .button-text .long-text {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(calc(100% - 2.6em));
  transform: translateY(calc(100% - 2.6em));
  max-height: 5.2em;
}

.button-container button.button .button-text .short {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 2.6em);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-container button.button .button-text .short-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="button">
    <div class="button-text">
      <div class="long">
        <div class="short">
          <div class="short-text">hi world</div>
        </div>
        <div class="long-text">hello universe!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```